# Help verifying expression involving dilogarithms.

Tags: special-functions, polylogarithm

I need help verifying that the following equality holds:

$$Li_2(-2-2\sqrt2)+Li_2(3-2\sqrt2)+Li_2(\frac{1}{\sqrt2})-Li_2(-\frac{1}{\sqrt2})-Li_2(2-\sqrt2)-Li_2(-1-\sqrt2)-2Li_2(-3+2\sqrt2)$$

$$=$$

$$\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\log(1+\sqrt2)\log(2+\sqrt2)-\log(3+2\sqrt2)\log(4-2\sqrt2)$$

using identities for the dilogarithm. I've tried every formula that I know of but haven't managed to make any progress.

Comment: Maybe you've considered this by now, but $3\pm2\sqrt2=\left(\sqrt2\pm1\right)^2$ so you can rewrite the dilogs of those expressions using the first identity listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilogarithm#Identities)